# Java input storage to SQL Database using prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

How can i take input using prepared statement using jtextfield to store it in sql database? I have used jtextfield for variables but by passing this as a parameter in prepared statement gives the following error message :- The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, JTextField). Can someone make me understand what is the problem and what solution can be applied

```
package employeemid;
        import employeemid.DatabaseConnection;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;    // importing event package for event listener
        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.Statement;
        public class RegForm{
            //Creating Static variables
            static JTextField name_txt ;
            static JTextField fname_txt;
            static JTextField mname_txt;
            static JTextField lname_txt;
            static JRadioButton male;
            static JRadioButton female;
            static JComboBox day;
            static JComboBox month;
            static JComboBox year;
            static JTextArea add_txtArea;
            static JTextField phone_txt;
            static JTextField email_txt;
            static JTextField pc_txt;
            static JTextField a_txt;
            static JCheckBox chkbox;
            static JButton submit_btn;
            static JTextArea output_txtArea;
            //public static void main(String args[])
            public RegForm()
            {
                /* ---------------------------------- Creating JFrame -------------------------------------------------------- */
                //  1 :  Creating a frame using JFrame class    
                JFrame frame=new JFrame("Registration Form Example");  
                frame.setVisible(true);      
                frame.setBounds(200,100,700,600 );    
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
                //  2 : setting background color of Frame.       
                Container c=frame.getContentPane();   
                c.setLayout(null);    
                c.setBackground(Color.cyan);     
                /*---------------------------------- Creating JLabel for Heading Text ------------------------------------------- */
                Font f=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);   // Creating font style and size for heading
                //  3 : creating JLabel for Heading
                JLabel heading_lbl=new JLabel();
                heading_lbl.setBounds(250,5,200,40);
                heading_lbl.setText("<html><font><u><b>Registration Form</b></u></html>");  
                // applying font on  heading Label
                heading_lbl.setFont(f);
                /* ----------------------------------- Creating Global Font style for all components ------------------------------ */
                Font f1=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,14);
                /* ----------------------------------- Creating components for Registration details ---------------------------------- */
                //  4 : Creating JLabel for Name
                JLabel name_lbl=new JLabel("Name : ");
                name_lbl.setBounds(50,80,100,30); 
                // Creating JTextField for Name
                name_txt=new JTextField();
                name_txt.setBounds(180,80,180,30);  
                //  5 : Creating JLabel for Father's Name
                JLabel fname_lbl=new JLabel("Father's Name : ");
                fname_lbl.setBounds(50,120,150,30);  
                // Creating JTextField for Father's name
                fname_txt=new JTextField();
                fname_txt.setBounds(180,120,180,30);
                //  6 : Creating JLabel for Mother's Name
                JLabel mname_lbl=new JLabel("Mother's Name : ");
                mname_lbl.setBounds(50,160,150,30);  
                // Creating JTextField for Mother's name
                mname_txt=new JTextField();
                mname_txt.setBounds(180,160,180,30);
                //  7 : Creating JLabel for Last Name
                JLabel lname_lbl=new JLabel("Last Name : ");
                lname_lbl.setBounds(50,200,150,30);  
                // Creating JTextField for Mother's name
                lname_txt=new JTextField();
                lname_txt.setBounds(180,200,180,30);
                //  8 : Creating JLabel for Gender
                JLabel gender_lbl=new JLabel("Gender : ");
                gender_lbl.setBounds(50,240,150,30);   
                // Setting Cursor for components
                Cursor cur=new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);      
                // Creating JRadioButton for the Male       
                male=new JRadioButton("Male");
                male.setBounds(180,240,70,30);
                male.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                male.setCursor(cur);
                // Creating JRadioButton for the Female
                female=new JRadioButton("Female");
                female.setBounds(280,240,80,30);
                female.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                female.setCursor(cur);
                // Creating ButtonGroup for the JRadioButtons
                ButtonGroup gender_grp=new ButtonGroup();
                gender_grp.add(male);    // adding male radio button in the ButtonGroup
                gender_grp.add(female);    // adding female radio button in the ButtonGroup
                //  9 : Creating JLabel for Date of Birth
                JLabel dob_lbl=new JLabel("Date of Birth : ");
                dob_lbl.setBounds(50,280,100,30);   
                // Creating JComboBox for the day
                String day_arr[]=new String[31];
                for(int i=1;i<=31;i++)
                    day_arr[i-1]=Integer.toString(i);       
                day=new JComboBox(day_arr);
                day.setBounds(180,280,40,30);
                // Creating JComboBox for the month
                String month_arr[]={"Jan","Feb","March","April","May","June","July","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec" };   
                month=new JComboBox(month_arr);
                month.setBounds(230,280,60,30);
                // Creating JComboBox for the year  
                String year_arr[]=new String[70];
                for(int i=1951;i<=2020;i++)
                    year_arr[i-1951]=Integer.toString(i);
                year=new JComboBox(year_arr);
                year.setBounds(300,280,60,30);
                //  10 : Creating JLabel for the Address
                JLabel add_lbl=new JLabel("Address : ");
                add_lbl.setBounds(50,320,100,30);               
                // Creating JTextArea for the address
                add_txtArea= new JTextArea();
                add_txtArea.setBounds(180,320,180,100);
                //  11 :  Creating JLabel for the phone
                JLabel phone_lbl=new JLabel("Phone No. : ");
                phone_lbl.setBounds(50,450,100,30);
                // Creating JTextField for the phone
                phone_txt=new JTextField();
                phone_txt.setBounds(180,450,180,30);
                //  12 : Creating JLabel for the Email
                JLabel email_lbl=new JLabel("Email : ");
                email_lbl.setBounds(50,490,100,30);
                // Creating JTextField for the Email
                email_txt=new JTextField();
                email_txt.setBounds(180,490,180,30);    
                //  13 : Creating JLabel for the Pan Card
                JLabel pc_lbl=new JLabel("PanCard no: ");
                pc_lbl.setBounds(50,530,100,30);
                // Creating JTextField for the pan card
                pc_txt=new JTextField();
                pc_txt.setBounds(180,530,180,30);                   
                //  14 : Creating JLabel for the Aadhaar
                JLabel a_lbl=new JLabel("Aadhar no : ");
                a_lbl.setBounds(50,570,100,30);
                // Creating JTextField for the Aadhar
                a_txt=new JTextField();
                a_txt.setBounds(180,570,180,30);                    
                //  15 : Creating JCheckBox for the license agreement       
                chkbox=new JCheckBox("I accept the terms and conditions");
                chkbox.setBounds(50,610,300,30);
                chkbox.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                //  16 : Creating JButton for submit the details
                submit_btn=new JButton("Submit");
                submit_btn.setBounds(180,680,120,40);
                submit_btn.setCursor(cur);  // Applying hand cursor on the button
                //  17 :  Adding ActionListener on submit button
                submit_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        submit_action(event);                                   
                    }           
                });
                //  18 : Creating JTextArea for output
                output_txtArea=new JTextArea();
                output_txtArea.setBounds(380,80,500,320);
                //  19 : Applying Global Font on all the JLabels    
                name_lbl.setFont(f1);
                fname_lbl.setFont(f1);
                mname_lbl.setFont(f1);
                lname_lbl.setFont(f1);
                gender_lbl.setFont(f1);
                dob_lbl.setFont(f1);
                add_lbl.setFont(f1);
                phone_lbl.setFont(f1);
                email_lbl.setFont(f1);
                pc_lbl.setFont(f1);
                a_lbl.setFont(f1);
                //  20 : Applying Font on all JTextFields, JRadioButtons, JComboBox and JTextArea
                name_txt.setFont(f1);
                fname_txt.setFont(f1);
                mname_txt.setFont(f1);
                lname_txt.setFont(f1);
                male.setFont(f1);
                female.setFont(f1);
                add_txtArea.setFont(f1);
                phone_txt.setFont(f1);
                email_txt.setFont(f1);
                pc_txt.setFont(f1);
                a_txt.setFont(f1);
                chkbox.setFont(f1);
                submit_btn.setFont(f1);
                output_txtArea.setFont(f1);
                //  21 : Adding label components to the container 
                c.add(heading_lbl); 
                c.add(name_lbl);            
                c.add(fname_lbl);
                c.add(mname_lbl);
                c.add(lname_lbl);
                c.add(gender_lbl);
                c.add(male);
                c.add(female);
                c.add(dob_lbl);
                c.add(add_lbl);
                c.add(phone_lbl);
                c.add(email_lbl);
                c.add(pc_lbl);
                c.add(a_lbl);
                //  22 : Adding JTextField, JTextArea, JComboBox, JCheckBox, JRadioButton to the container
                c.add(name_txt);
                c.add(name_txt);
                c.add(fname_txt);
                c.add(mname_txt);
                c.add(lname_txt);
                c.add(day);
                c.add(month);
                c.add(year);
                c.add(add_txtArea);
                c.add(phone_txt);
                c.add(email_txt);
                c.add(pc_txt);
                c.add(a_txt);
                c.add(chkbox);
                c.add(submit_btn);
                c.add(output_txtArea);                          
            }
            //  23 : Reading value from the Registration Form
            public static void submit_action(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event){
                if(chkbox.isSelected()==true)
                {
                    String name=name_txt.getText();
                    String fname=fname_txt.getText();
                    String mname=mname_txt.getText();
                    String lname=lname_txt.getText();
                    String gender="Male";
                    if(female.isSelected()==true)
                        gender="Female";
                    String day_name=(String)day.getSelectedItem();
                    String month_name=(String)month.getSelectedItem();
                    String year_name=(String)year.getSelectedItem();
                    String add=add_txtArea.getText();
                    String phone=phone_txt.getText();
                    String email=email_txt.getText();
                    String pc=pc_txt.getText();
                    String a=a_txt.getText();
                    //PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement
                    //String query = "insert into data(Name,MiddleName,LastName,gender,Bday,Bmonth,Byear,Address,PhoneNo,Mail,PAN,Addhar) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    try {
                        Connection conn_1 = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
                        //Statement stmt = conn_1.createStatement();
                        //first you "prepare" your statement (where the '?' acts as a kind of placeholder)
                        PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) conn_1.prepareStatement( "insert into data (Name,MiddleName,LastName,gender,Bday,Bmonth,Byear,Address,PhoneNo,Mail,PAN,Addhar) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
                        //String query =
                        //now you bind the data to your parameters
                        st.setString(1, name_txt);//error from here
                        st.setString(2, fname_txt);
                        st.setString(3, mname_txt);
                        st.setString(4, lname_txt);
                        st.setString(5, gender);
                        st.setString(6, day);
                        st.setString(7, month);
                        st.setString(8, year);
                        st.setString(9, add_txtArea);
                        st.setString(10, phone_txt);
                        st.setString(11, email_txt);
                        st.setString(12, pc_txt);
                        st.setString(13, a_txt);
                        //and then you can execute it
                        st.executeUpdate();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    // displaying value in the JTextArea
                    output_txtArea.setText(" Name :   " +name + "\n Father's Name :  " +fname +"\nMother's Name: "+mname+"\nLastName: "+lname+ "\n Gender :   "+gender +
                            "\n Date of Birth :   "+day_name + "  "+month_name + " " +year_name +  
                            "\n Address :  "+add + " \n Phone no :  "+phone + 
                            "\n Email :  "+email + "\nPan Card no: "+pc+ "\nAadhaar no"+a+ "\n ");
                }
                else
                {
                    output_txtArea.setText("Please accept the terms and condition");
                }
            }
            /*public void reset() {
                       for(JTextField field : fieldList) {
                          field.setText("");
                       }
                    }*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
st.setString(1, name_txt);
st.setString(2, fname_txt);
st.setString(3, mname_txt);
st.setString(4, lname_txt);
...
st.setString(9, add_txtArea);
st.setString(10, phone_txt);
st.setString(11, email_txt);
st.setString(12, pc_txt);
st.setString(13, a_txt);
```

to

```
st.setString(1, name);
st.setString(2, fname);
st.setString(3, mname);
st.setString(4, lname);
...
st.setString(9, add);
st.setString(10, phone);
st.setString(11, email);
st.setString(12, pc);
st.setString(13, a);
```

Becuase you assigned these strings to variables:

```
String name=name_txt.getText();
String fname=fname_txt.getText();
String mname=mname_txt.getText();
String lname=lname_txt.getText();
...
String add=add_txtArea.getText();
String phone=phone_txt.getText();
String email=email_txt.getText();
String pc=pc_txt.getText();
String a=a_txt.getText();
```

Comment: thanks I tried using that first before switching to .gettext() It takes input but but storing values is where the error occurs

Comment: I have no idea what you just said

Comment: i previously used some some method to take input before switching to  .gettext() which is the right syntax for taking input